# How to convert pojo attributes to database column names

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to generate database column name from POJO fields. For example, if pojo has field as

```
origOrderDate --> ORIG_ORDER_DATE
custName --> CUST_NAME
firstOrigDatePort --> FIRST_ORIG_DATE_PORT
...
...
```

I have following code,

```
String testStr = "origOrderDate";
String regEx = "([A-Z])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found %d, of capital letters in %s%n", matcher.groupCount(), testStr);
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "_$1");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().toUpperCase());
```

It loses ending part of the string. Any ideas?

```
ORIG_ORDER_D
```

Comment: You need to put [`matcher.appendTail(sb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code, to achieve what you are doing in just one line:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       String testStr = "origOrderDate";
       String convertedString = testStr.replaceAll("(\\p{Upper})", "_$1").toUpperCase();
       System.out.println(convertedString);
   }
```

In above code: The expression \p{Upper} will match every upper case letter and replace it with _UppercaseCharacter.

As per @Pedro Pinheiro, we can also do:-

```
String convertedString = testStr.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1").toUpperCase();
```

Comment: In other words: ``([A-Z])``

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [`matcher.appendTail`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-) to append the end of the String. Quoting [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) Javadoc:

> The appendReplacement and appendTail methods can be used in tandem in order to collect the result into an existing string buffer

```
String testStr = "origOrderDate";
String regEx = "([A-Z])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found %d, of capital letters in %s%n", matcher.groupCount(), testStr);
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "_$1");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString().toUpperCase());
```

Note that another option to do this is to use Google Guava's [`CaseFormat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html):

```
CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE, "origOrderDate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex will work, but here is another easy and cleaner way with gauva.

```
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.*;

String columnName = LOWER_CAMEL.to(UPPER_UNDERSCORE, "origOrderDate");
```

The reverse conversion would be,

```
String fieldName = UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(LOWER_CAMEL, "ORIG_ORDER_DATE")
```